# 正規表現で特定の記号に挟まれた語を抽出したい

Tags: 正規表現

サクラエディタで `*` に挟まれた語だけを抽出したいです。

```
Setiap manusia dapat menyesuaikan dengan kadar kecerdasan , ***pemahaman*** dan pengetahuan yang dimilikinya .
Bayi anda ***memahami*** suara tinggi dan bunyian aneh yang anda buat .
```

上のようなデータから以下のように語を抽出したいです。

```
***pemahaman***
***memahami***
```

どのような正規表現を使ってGrep検索をすれば期待する結果が得られるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*`3個を正規表現で表すと`\*{3}`です。
  1個以上の単語構成文字(下記参照)を正規表現で表すと`\w+`です。

[サクラエディタのヘルプファイル](https://sakura-editor.github.io/help/HLP000089.html)によると、単語の構成文字 `[0-9A-Za-z_]`と同じであり、`bregonig.dll`使用時は2バイト文字も含みます。
 そのため上記以外の文字列を含むご質問の回答としては @asarikz さんの正規表現が適切です。

以下は囲まれた文字に*を含まない想定で記述した別解です。
 `\*{3}\w+\*{3}`

```
 □検索条件  "\*{3}\w+\*{3}"
 検索対象   *.*
 フォルダ   C:\test\sakura
     (サブフォルダも検索)
     (英大文字小文字を区別しない)
     (正規表現:bregonig.dll Ver.3.06 with Onigmo 5.15.0)
     (文字コードセットの自動判別)
     (一致した行を出力)


 C:\sakura\hoge.txt(1,61)  [SJIS]: Setiap manusia dapat menyesuaikan dengan kadar kecerdasan , ***pemahaman*** dan pengetahuan yang dimilikinya .
 C:\sakura\hoge.txt(2,11)  [SJIS]: Bayi anda ***memahami*** suara tinggi dan bunyian aneh yang anda buat .
 2 個が検索されました。
```

Comment: `***`に囲まれた文字列に`*`が含まれる場合(1個か2個)ヒットしないようです。※`[*]{3}.+?[*]{3}`はヒットしました。

Comment: `\w+`は「1個以上のスペースを除く任意の文字列」ではないですね。初心者も読まれるであろうこの質問スレでは致命的な誤りだと思われるので、書き直していただいた方が良いように思います。

Comment: 修正しました。初心者向けの回答のつもりでしたが、不適切で混乱を招く回答となりましたことをお詫びします。

Answer (score 3):

おそらく次の正規表現で十分だと思います。

```
[*]{3}.+?[*]{3}
```